# which binary for php5.3 to download?

Tags: php, windows

Referring following link

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows

There are thread-safe, non-thread safe and with this it is also prefixed with VC6,VC8,VC9.

I have window 7 Ent and I am not able to understand which binary (.dll) I should download from here.

How am I suppose to know which dll I have to download ?

How to identify which VC compiler + thread safe or non-thread safe combination to choose ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell which PHP install you have, from the command line, run this command:

```
php -i | more
```

This will dump phpinfo page by page.  On the second page or so, you should see a "Zend Extension Build" and/or a "PHP Extension Build" key under the "System" section.  Maybe it will display something like "API###, TS, VC9".  TS stands for "thread safe" (which actually also shows as enabled/disabled in the "Thread Safety" key just a bit below that).  "VC9" stands for... VC9.  You already know you have PHP5.3 installed.  This means you want to install the PHP5.3 Threadsafe VC9 version of Mongo.

Also, this is an example of when user provided comments in the PHP manual page are very helpful.  Check the first comment by Andrey 01-Jun-2011 11:54.

Comment: +1 good info, except for your edit at the end: it seems the version of VC you have installed locally is irrelevant in this context, unless you yourself used it to build apache/php from source.

Comment: @Frank Farmer: thanks.  Removed.  I mixed up "VC" with "C++ Runtime" requirement.

Comment: the-destroyer +1 good info, Very useful and now I know which binaries to download .Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

On http://windows.php.net/download/ there's a 'Which version do I choose?' section on the left.

> Which version do I choose?
>
> If you are
>   using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2
>   from apache.org you need to use the
>   VC6 versions of PHP
>
> If you are using PHP with IIS you
>   should use the VC9 versions of PHP
>
> VC6 Versions are compiled with the
>   legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler
>
> VC9 Versions are compiled with the
>   Visual Studio 2008 compiler and have
>   improvements in performance and
>   stability. The VC9 versions require
>   you to have the Microsoft 2008 C++
>   Runtime (x86) or the Microsoft 2008
>   C++ Runtime (x64) installed
>
> Do NOT use VC9 version with apache.org
>   binaries
>
> VC9 versions of Apache can be fetched
>   at Apache Lounge. We use their
>   binaries to build the Apache SAPIs.

Comment: @Frank Farmer Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running Windows 7, downloading VC9 would be ideal.

If your App needs to be thread safe, then download Thread safe one. If you are not sure if your application needs to be Thread Safe, you probably won't need Thread Safe Version anyway.

Comment: how I will identify which VC version?

Comment: The VC version indicates which version of VC was used to build the solution. Under most circumstances, it doesn't actually matter much. What would matter is to ensure that your version is the same as the one used for deployment.